# Is there an easy way to multiply each element with each other in array / list - Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have got `{1,2,3}` / or it might be a `list<Int>` is there an easy way to multiply each element with each other like `1*2 , 1*3, 2*3` ?

Comment: Would the resulting list have six elements so it has all permutations? There's no built-in function for something like this so specific, if that's what you mean by easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work, given that you probably don't want to include the duplicates  like `items[i] * items[j]` and `items[j] * items[i]`

```kotlin
val items = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)

val result = items.flatMapIndexed { index, a -> 
    items.subList(index + 1, items.size).map { b -> a * b }
}

println(result) // [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]
```

- [`flatMapIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map-indexed.html) builds a list for each of the `items` elements by evaluating the lambda on the index and the item, and then concatenates the lists.
- [`subList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/sub-list.html) is an efficient way to take the items in the specific range: starting at the next index, and until the end of the list.

Comment: And you could include each item squared (multiplied by itself) by simply removing the `+ 1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the old-fashioned way: nested loops

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list = listOf( 1, 2, 3 )
    
    for (i in list.indices) {
        for (j in (i + 1) until list.size) {
            println("${list[i]} * ${list[j]} = ${list[i] * list[j]}")
        }
    }
}
```

Output of this code:

```
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3
2 * 3 = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *did* want all the permutations (every possible ordering), you could do something like this:

```
val result = with(items) {
    flatMapIndexed { i, first ->
        slice(indices - i).map { second -> // combine first and second here }
    }
}
```

[`slice`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/slice.html) lets you provide a list of indices for the elements you want to pull, so you can easily exclude the current index and get all the *other* elements to combo it with. Takes an `IntRange` too, so you can do `slice(i+1 until size)` to get the combination (every pairing) functionality too.

Not as efficient as *hotkey's* `subList` version (since that doesn't make a copy) but you can get two behaviours this way so I thought I'd mention it! But if I were making a reusable function rather than a quick one-liner, I'd probably go with `deHaar`'s approach with the nested for loops, it's efficient and easy enough to tweak for either behaviour